# what am I missing here? jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, carousel

I'm pretty new in programming and currently mostly learning a lot from my own mistakes. But I can't seem to figure out what I am missing or doing wrong with this particular piece of coding.
I am trying to make this Bootstrap Carousel 'swipe touch' compatible, and I use the jQuery Mobile plugin. But it doesn't seem to bind to the Carousel. Here is a part of the code for the Carousel, followed by the script.
I also linked the bootstrap files etc. but that might not be relevant to see in this case.
Now what am I missing here? My apologies if it is so obvious, like I said, I'm new and still have a lot to learn.

```
<link href="jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
       <img src="img/test" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
             <a href="test/test.htm"><h2 class="carousel-text">Page1</h2></a>
          </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="item">
       <img src="img/test2" alt="test2" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
             <a href="test/test2.htm"><h2 class="carousel-text">Page2</h2></a>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
     <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
            $(this).carousel('prev');  
        });  
        $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
            $(this).carousel('next');  
        });  
    });  
 </script>
```